# NSDate() function return date ff year instead Date of month. How to return date of month?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I get problem with return today Date, instead return date of month xcode swift (Version 8.1 (8T61a)) return day of year. Example today 2016-11-07 call NSDate() ==> try to return string with format YYYY-MM-DD value return I got 2016-11-312 (312 is the days of the year 2016) how can I return date of month 07 instead date of year 312?

```
@IBAction func stringTodayDate(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let helloDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    helloDateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    let todayDate = helloDateFormatter.string(from: NSDate() as Date)
    print(todayDate)
```

today 2016-11-07
The function above return: 2016-11-312

how to return 07 instead 312

thank you.

Comment: FYI, rather than `NSDate() as Date`, you can just do `Date()`.

Answer (score 2):

- `DD` is day of **year**
- `YYYY` is year in 'Week of Year' based calendars

You're looking for

```
helloDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

Take a look at [unicode.org: Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

PS: Use native struct `Date()` to get rid of the type cast.